# How to add properties to react-router-redux LOCATION_CHANGE?

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am writing an application using [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux). When the `LOCATION_CHANGE` action is dispatched, I want to update the UI to show progress based on how far in a survey the user is. My state has this structure:

```
ui: {
  progress: 0
},
survey: {
  question1: true,
  question2: null
}
```

I have a function that loops through the questions in the survey property and can determine the progress based on the first instance of a question being `null`. In the above example, the progress will be 1 as question2 is `null` (yet to be answered).

To update the UI, I have a UI reducer subscribed to the `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action, in which I can run the function to determine progress.

The problem I am facing is that in the UI reducer, I only have access to the UI state and the payload from `LOCATION_CHANGE`, not the survey.

Is it possible to modify `LOCATION_CHANGE` to include additional properties in its payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve your problem in my opinion is to use a middleware to intercept all `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` actions and execute your logic before it reaches the reducer. You have the `getState` function available in middleware so you can read both `ui` and `survery` states.

**Middleware**

```
export default ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.type === '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE') {
    const state = getState(); // this is the whole redux state
    const progress = getNewProgressValue(state);
    dispatch(updateProgress(progress)); // updateProgress is the action creator to update progress value
  }
  next(action);
}
```

You also need to modify your reducer to update `progress` based on action dispatched by `updateProgress` action creator.

NOTE: I'm assuming you're not using `redux-saga`. If you are, you can still get the idea from this method.